# Stack Overflow as an OpenID provider?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

With all the new sites going on, I think Stack Overflow knows more about me than my current OpenID provider.

Isn't it about time to have Stack Overflow as an OpenID provider?

[image: Confirm OpenID]

I would rather have OpenID credentials provided by Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 win http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/#comment-59132 only took a year ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are already more than enough OpenID providers. What OpenID really needs is more sites to support it as the primary login system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Do you really want to log into blogs, forums, and other sites with a Stack Overflow OpenID? Why put extra work on Stack Overflow servers and maintainers when the OpenID site, Gmail, and countless other sites do it perfectly well?

Comment: *Do you really [...] with a stackoverflow open-id?* Oh definitely... *Why put extra work on SO servers and maintainers?* Isn't that the reason they got all those millions of dollars? To be able to purchase and "extra" server and pay an "extra" developer if needed?, Beside I don't spend that much time in all those open id providers ( look mine, I have only 2 blog entries )

Comment: @Crazy, I don't think they do it well, I've been kept out of SO because of provider downtime before.

Comment: @Oscar put it this way: do you really think MOST people would like to do that? Even if SO has millions of dollars to blow, there's many better ways to spend it than offering something that tons of other sites already do. What next, a stackoverflow search engine? Is that really worthwhile? Let's not waste millions on what google is already doing with billions. Let's use it to do something nobody's ever done before and be unparalleled at it instead of creating a mediocre product that will never stand a chance against thousands of competitors. :D

Comment: @Lance Interesting, I've never had that problem. Do you really think SO could do it better than google? (see previous comment)

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer Well I wasn't thinking on MOST people, but only in interested StackOverflow users :-/  I don't mean to have it as open service where anyone can come and have one or as competing OpenId product, but as an extension of SO users only. I agree with you in the argument of not repeating existing services, but I definitely don't think the reason should be *"They're doing better job already and StackOverflow won't ever be as capable"*

Comment: @Crazy, no, I'm not sure they could, but at least my SO time would only be cut short if SO itself is actually having a problem