# Unusual 404 errors from meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support

I've just received a very generic/plain 404 error page from attempting to navigate to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=activity#tab-top (via: [Stack Overflow as an OpenID provider?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57449/stackoverflow-as-openid-provider)) as per the screenshot:

[image]

Is this another artifact of the "new caching tech" mentioned as the answer to [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63407/intermittent-offline-messages/)?

Comment: Cannot Reproduce. http://xkcd.com/583/

Comment: @Chacha, as per my previous question, this is/was intermittent. Whilst amusing, a link to xkcd is entirely unhelpful.

Comment: but it is (im)pertinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means you caught us in the middle of deploying a new revision of the website -- nothing to be concerned about.

(And meta is not load balanced..)

Comment: How do you deploy updates? I asked a question about this sometime ago but haven't gotten an answer yet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60963/how-are-updates-deployed-to-production - thanks so much!